# UNIQUE constraint failed: user_profile.StudentID error

Tags: django, unique-constraint, django-errors

[image]I am getting this error(IntegrityError at /register/) every time I try to create a new user. In user creation form I am creating both User and profile.
here is my models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    StudentID = models.CharField(max_length=8,unique=True)
    Branch = models.CharField(max_length=255,choices=Departments,default="CSE")
    YearOfStudy = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    ContactNumber = PhoneField(help_text='Contact phone number')
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpeg' , upload_to='profile_pics')
    parentsContactNumber = PhoneField(help_text="Parent's phone number")

    def __str__(self):
         return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

here is forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','first_name','last_name','password1','password2']

class ProfileCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['StudentID','Branch','YearOfStudy','ContactNumber']
```

here is views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        form1 = ProfileCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and form1.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form1.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
        form1 = ProfileCreationForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'form1': form1
    }
    return render(request, 'user/register.html', context)
```

here is register.html

```
 {% block content %}
        <div class="content-section">
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">JOIN TODAY</legend>
                    {{ form|crispy }}
                    {{ form1|crispy }}
                </fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    {% endblock content %}
```

please help me with this error

Comment: Can you please post image of your error or full stractrace of error ?

Comment: i have added error image in my question .

Answer (score 0):

You are set `unique=True` in...

```
StudentID = models.CharField(max_length=8,unique=True)
```

So, when you pass student_id from your form at that time you pass the same id in form which is already in your database thus this error is coming.

Comment: StudentID should be unique or it is possible to same studentID ?

Comment: Then simple please do not fill the same studentID while submitting the form

Comment: the how will I fill studentID field ? because it is only in profile model

Comment: you can also set it to primary key.

Comment: Did you try to set like this `StudentID = models. AutoField(primary_key=True) ? Or other way ?
`

Comment: did you run makemigrations and migrate command after change that field?